# How to zoom in on multiple points of a map and include them all in separate panels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, r-sf, terra

I have multiple polygons and a raster that make up my map. I would like to "zoom" into each of these polygons in order to better visualize the raster information within each of the polygons. I figure i can eventually use some combination of `facet_grid` and `ggdraw` for the final map, but for now I need help creating the "zoomed in" portion of the map.

Example:

```
#Raster layer
library(terra)
library(raster)
library(sf)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)

#polygons
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
v <- v[c(1:10)] 

#Base plot
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = r, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = elev)) +
  geom_sf(data = v, fill = NA, col = "red")
```

I know both the `raster` and `terra` packages have a `zoom` function, but i'm unable to use it with ggplot. Any guidance would be welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get your example data to work, however you can zoom in on portions of a `ggplot` using either:

```
your_plot+
   coord_cartesian(
      xlim = c(xmin, xmax), 
      ylim = c(ymin, ymax)
   )
```

or

```
your_plot+
   xlim(xmin, xmax)+
   ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

or

```
your_plot+
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(xmin, xmax))+
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(ymin, ymax))
```

Be aware that the latter 2 examples actually 'cut off' data points outside the 'zoomed' area, so for example lines or polygons which extend beyond the zoomed area will look different. `coord_cartesian` doesn't cut points off, and in this instance is probably what you want. This is explained nicely in the ggplot2 cheatsheet [found here](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/)

[image]

Additionally, if you are plotting an `sf` object using `geom_sf()`, you can also use `coord_sf()`, which is designed to handle spatial data, and also does not 'cut off' data which extends outside the plot area.

```
your_plot+
   coord_sf(
      xlim = c(xmin, xmax), 
      ylim = c(ymin, ymax)
   )
```

One tip: make sure the `min` value is less than the `max` value when specifying the limits. This might sound obvious, but for example here in Australia our latitudes (`y` values) are all negative. Therefore, it's easy to accidently confuse the 'smaller' number with the 'larger' number.

One way to arrange your individual zoomed plots into one is by using `cowplot::plot_grid` ([cowplot documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cowplot/versions/1.1.1/topics/plot_grid)). As a very basic example, you simply provide it with `ggplot` objects you want to arrange together (see documentation)

```
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4)
```